# How to bind event to multiple selectmenu change in jquerymobile

Tags: dom, jquery-mobile

I want to refresh my page when I finish choosing the selects in jquerymobile.Now Im using the onchange attribute in  tag.here's my code.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style = "background-color:white;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">select specity:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu = false multiple=true onchange = "selectChange()"></select>
</div>

$("#select-choice-1").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < item.tagClassList.length; i++) {
    if (item.tagClassList[i].isSelected) {
        $("#select-choice-1").append("<option value="+item.tagClassList[i].id+"checked = true>"+item.tagClassList[i].className+"</option>");
    } else {
        $("#select-choice-1").append("<option value="+item.tagClassList[i].id+">"+item.tagClassList[i].className+"</option>");
    }
    if (i == item.tagClassList.length-1) {
        $("#select-choice-1").selectmenu("refresh");
    };
};
```

But the selectmenu() event fires whenever select is selected or selected is cancelled.How can I get the event fires when the selectmenu is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try binding to blur() like so

```
$('document').on('blur', '#select-choice-1', function(){
    //run your check here
    });
```

this also takes care of older versions of ios which seem to not fire change events on multiple selects.